# Match and Remove Duplicate Values from Delimited String against another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to match and remove duplicates from a delimited string against another column. Can this be done with Cross Apply?

Example:

TABLE A:

```
"NAMES","REMOVE"
"James;Kevin;Dave","Kevin"
"Dale;Gordon;Thomas","Dale"
"Anthony;Brian","Brian"
```

RESULT:

```
"NEW NAMES","REMOVE"
"James;Dave","Kevin"
"Gordon;Thomas","Dale"
"Anthony","Brian"
```

As you can see I'm looking for a way to split the values from Names, match on the Remove column, and remove that name into a new field "New Names".

Comment: Related reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply replace the name.

```
SELECT *, 
 STUFF(REPLACE(';'+[NAMES], ';'+[REMOVE], ''), 1, 1,'') as [NEW NAMES]
FROM YourTable
```

But that method can give wrong results in some cases.
For example  when removing "Bob" from "John;Bobby;Bob" it would result in "Johnby".

In Sql Server 2017+ a combination of `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` is a safer method.

**Examples:**

> ```
> create table yourtable
> (
>    NAMES varchar(100),
>    REMOVE varchar(30)
> );
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO yourtable (NAMES, REMOVE) VALUES
> ('James;Kevin;Dave', 'Kevin'),
> ('Dale;Gordon;Thomas', 'Dale'),
> ('Anthony;Brian', 'Brian'),
> ('John;Bobby;Bob', 'Bob');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Simple replace & stuff
> -- WARNING: could give wrong results
> --
> SELECT t.*
> , STUFF(REPLACE(';'+[NAMES],';'+[REMOVE],''),1,1,'') AS [NEW NAMES]
> FROM YourTable t;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> NAMES              | REMOVE | NEW NAMES    
> :----------------- | :----- | :------------
> James;Kevin;Dave   | Kevin  | James;Dave   
> Dale;Gordon;Thomas | Dale   | Gordon;Thomas
> Anthony;Brian      | Brian  | Anthony      
> John;Bobby;Bob     | Bob    | Johnby
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Not so simple but safer replace
> --
> SELECT t.*, 
> ISNULL(LEFT(STUFF(REPLACE(';'+[NAMES]+';',';'+[REMOVE]+';',';'),1,1,''), NULLIF(LEN(STUFF(REPLACE(';'+[NAMES]+';',';'+[REMOVE]+';',';'),1,1,'')),0)-1),'') as [NEW NAMES]
> FROM YourTable t;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> NAMES              | REMOVE | NEW NAMES    
> :----------------- | :----- | :------------
> James;Kevin;Dave   | Kevin  | James;Dave   
> Dale;Gordon;Thomas | Dale   | Gordon;Thomas
> Anthony;Brian      | Brian  | Anthony      
> John;Bobby;Bob     | Bob    | John;Bobby
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Replace & trim
> -- Sql Server 2017+
> -- 
> SELECT t.*
> , TRIM(';' FROM REPLACE(';'+[NAMES]+';', ';'+[REMOVE]+';', ';')) AS [NEW NAMES]
> FROM YourTable t
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> NAMES              | REMOVE | NEW NAMES    
> :----------------- | :----- | :------------
> James;Kevin;Dave   | Kevin  | James;Dave   
> Dale;Gordon;Thomas | Dale   | Gordon;Thomas
> Anthony;Brian      | Brian  | Anthony      
> John;Bobby;Bob     | Bob    | John;Bobby
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- String_split & string_agg
> -- Sql Server 2017+
> -- 
> SELECT t.*, a.[NEW NAMES]
> FROM yourtable t
> CROSS APPLY
> (
>   SELECT 
>    STRING_AGG(s.value,';') as [NEW NAMES]
>   FROM STRING_SPLIT(t.[NAMES],';') s
>   WHERE s.value != t.[REMOVE]
> ) a;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> NAMES              | REMOVE | NEW NAMES    
> :----------------- | :----- | :------------
> James;Kevin;Dave   | Kevin  | James;Dave   
> Dale;Gordon;Thomas | Dale   | Gordon;Thomas
> Anthony;Brian      | Brian  | Anthony      
> John;Bobby;Bob     | Bob    | John;Bobby
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=973d86dc64f822387cbeeeac22ef7ae2)*